# Как заменить запятую точкой при вводе числа?

Tags: python

```
while True:
    import math

    print('-'*50)
    print('{:^50}\n{:^50}\n{:^50}'.format('Лабораторная работа №2', 'Функция: tan(2*atan(x))'))
    print('-'*50)

    try:
        a = float(input('Введите a: '))
        b = float(input('Введите b: '))
        if a > b:
            print('произошла ошибка: недопустимое значение промежутка!')
            continue
        else:
            h = float(input('Введите h: '))

        x = a

    except:
        print('произошла ошибка: некорректно введены данные!')
        continue

    f = open('lab2.txt', 'w')
    f.write("\n"'---------------------------------')
    while x <= float(b):
         if x == -1.0 or x == 1:
            f.write("\n"'!{:^ 10.1f}!{:^20}!'.format(x, 'не существует'))
            f.write("\n"'---------------------------------')
         else:
            f.write("\n"'!{:^ 10.1f}!{:^ 19.3f} !'.format(x, math.tan(2 * math.atan(x))))
            f.write("\n"'---------------------------------')
         x += h
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользоваться функцией замены одного символа на другой:

```
 a = float(input('Введите a: ').replace(',', '.'))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо